# Convert a query string to user friendly URL

Tags: php, url-rewriting

how to convert this url
http://www.example.com/category_listing.php?city=Bangalore&search=Astrology&submit=Go
into
http://www.example.com/Bangalore/Astrology

Comment: Reposting won't get you an answer. This topic has been covered ad nauseam, and you're not overly burdened with a little googling and research of your own.

Comment: Googling? He already gave the answer by tagging his "question" with `url-rewriting`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way to do it.
First, turn on mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`
Like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . category_listing.php
```

Next, you need to parse the query string in `category_listing.php`

For example:

```
$query = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$city = $query[0]; // 'Bangalore'
$search = $query[1]; // 'Astrology'
```

Play with array indices, it may be 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1 depending on your server settings.

That's all it takes!